# invalid LOC header (bad signature) for hive jars

Tags: java, maven, hive, hdfs

I'm trying to connect to hive using JDBC connection.
Here are my dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libfb303</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm getting the below exception when I do `mvn package`. Same exception when exporting the jar from Eclipse and running the jar

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project connector: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] error: error reading /home/krishnaprasad/.m2/repository/org/apache/hive/hive-llap-server/2.1.0/hive-llap-server-2.1.0.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading /home/krishnaprasad/.m2/repository/org/apache/hive/hive-serde/2.1.0/hive-serde-2.1.0.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading /home/krishnaprasad/.m2/repository/org/apache/hive/hive-metastore/2.1.0/hive-metastore-2.1.0.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading /home/krishnaprasad/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-api-jdo/4.2.1/datanucleus-api-jdo-4.2.1.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading /home/krishnaprasad/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-rdbms/4.1.7/datanucleus-rdbms-4.1.7.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading /home/krishnaprasad/.m2/repository/org/apache/hive/hive-service-rpc/2.1.0/hive-service-rpc-2.1.0.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading /home/krishnaprasad/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/4.1.6/datanucleus-core-4.1.6.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Any suggestions?